# SQL Server date conversion fails due to some user/db setting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Which user/db setting would cause the date conversion here to fail with `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`?

```
SELECT
    -- This works:
    CONVERT(datetime2, '01 ' + LEFT([MonthName], 3) + ' ' + CAST([Year] as char(4)), 106)

    -- This doesn't:
    ,CONVERT(datetime2, '01 ' + LEFT([MonthName], 3) + ' 2018', 106)
```

`[Year]` is of type `int NOT NULL`.

`[MonthName]` is of type `nvarchar(100) NOT NULL` and its collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

`DBCC USEROPTIONS` shows this:

```
language   | us_english
dateformat | mdy
```

I tried creating another table with seemingly the same settings and the query works there. Something is obviously different but I can't figure out what.

**EDIT**

Doing a `SELECT DISTINCT [Year], [MonthName]` reveals that there's data only for 'December', 2017. So yes, the month name is in English.

Leap years can't be the problem because of the previous point but also because I'm forcing the day to be 1.

Interestingly, `TRY_CONVERT` doesn't return `NULL` for any row. I did a

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, '01 ' + LEFT([MonthName], 3) + ' 2018', 106) IS NULL
```

I'm suspecting that inputting the `' 2018'` causes the resulting string to be of some other collation (or something) which makes SQL Server expect the date format to be something different.

Here's the weird part. The query works if it's like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(datetime2, + LEFT([MonthName], 3) + '01 2018', 106)
    ,CONVERT(datetime2, '01 ' + LEFT([MonthName], 3) + ' 2018', 106)
    ,[Year]
```

But removing either the `[Year]` or the `DISTINCT` will again produce the same error.

The query has only two tables joined in the `FROM` clause and no `WHERE` clause. The `[MonthName]` comes from the second table and the `[Year]` from the first.

Comment: If you set off individual `select...` statements for each `CONVERT()` what error message do you receive for the second statement?

Comment: If the second `CONVERT()` is the only statement in the `SELECT` statement, I get the `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` error.

Comment: Using `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CONVERT` and including the base columns of your select might reveal something with your data.  `TRY_CONVERT` will return `NULL` if the conversion fails.

Comment: What data is stored in the `MonthName` column? Are you using English month names or possibly another language?

Comment: Could it be leap years?  Check your data for values of February 29th.

Comment: What does the rest of the query look like? Could you share an estimated execution plan for the query that fails? Perhaps you are filtering out invalid rows in a where clause and in the case it fails the conversion is done earlier in plan than when it works.

Comment: Is a screenshot sufficient for the estimated execution plan?

Comment: Take the XML and paste it here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and update your question with a link.

Comment: I guess you have invalid month names in your second table that gets filtered out by the join to the first table. When the query fails, the conversion is done for all rows in the second table, before the join.

Comment: Well, that kind of makes sense. The second table does have names that are not valid month names but wouldn't this be considered a bug then? `SELECT` comes almost last in the logical processing order and certainly after `FROM`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement

Comment: That is the *logical* order of processing. What you have to deal with when writing the query. After the query optimizer is done with creating an execution plan it can look very different. From the link you provided **"The actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list."**